# PHP for loop mysql array values insert - inserting 100 000 rows instead of array length

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, for-loop

The question should be clear, but I'll explain once more:
I'm trying to insert the individual values from an array in a mysql database.

Here is the code:

```
public function addRoute($pointArray){

    $length = 4; //just to be sure that nothing went wrong with calulating the length

    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){

        $result = "INSERT into route_point(latlng, routeID) VALUES (4849, 10)"; //sample values, to once again be sure that there is nothing wrong with the values
        mysql_query($result);
    }

    mysql_close(); //just to be sure again
    return true;
}
```

The pointArray is being passed from actionscript using the zendamf framework if anyone is wondering. In my eyes nothing is wrong with the statement, but instead of inserting 4 rows, it inserts more than 100 000 rows.. I also don't receive the "true" back in actionscript, which should be passed when the php function is executed.

I also tried a for each loop, but I get an error (which I can't read since i'm calling the php file from actionscript).

```
foreach ($pointArray as $value) {

        $result = "INSERT into route_point(latlng, routeID) VALUES ('$value', 10)";
        mysql_query($result);

    }
```

I prefer to use a for loop though.

Absolutely clueless on this, fiddled with several settings for a couple of hours now.

Comment: Actionscript doesn't support "sparse" arrays for output. If you do `arr[500] = 1` in AS, and then send it out via AMF or JSON or whatever, the output data will be built with array elements 1 through 499 defined as well, not just #500, so you're sending 500 elements, not 1.

Comment: I've been able to see PHP errors through zendamf by using the Network tab of Chrome's developer tools.  It helps to run `$server->setProduction(!DEBUG)` on the Zend_Amf_Server instance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `addRoute` is only called once? And the PHP file is called only once? I would ask what's in `$pointArray` but that doesn't really matter in this case =)

You could put a log in the `addRoute` function (write to file `$file=microtime(1).'.log'` to see how often it's called. You could build the log contents (of every `addRoute` call) in the `for` loop:

```
public function addRoute($pointArray){

$length = 4; 
//just to be sure that nothing went wrong with calulating the length

$log = '';
for($i = 0; $i &lt; $length; $i++){

    $log .= $i."\n"

    $result = "INSERT into route_point(latlng, routeID) VALUES (4849, 10)"; 
    //sample values, 
    //to once again be sure that there is nothing wrong with the values
    mysql_query($result);
}

file_put_contents(microtime(1).'.log', $log);

mysql_close(); //just to be sure again
return true;
}
```

And then see what really happened =)

Comment: Thanks! The error is resolved, I have no idea how but it suddenly worked o_O
Things it had to do with the conversion between actionscript array and php array..
Anyway, the next problem is that in the loop, sending $pointArray[$i] returns an error ("INSERT into route_point(latlng) VALUES ('$pointArray[$i]')"). It works perfectly fine using $pointArray[0], something is wrong with the $i part.

Comment: You might want to add the result from mysql_error() to the log too. And even better: learn to use a debugger (Xdebug or such). es the can be combined with such services

Comment: I'll take a look. Not being able to see the specific error message is very annoying.